# Rails form_with hidden_field value encrypted for new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field, ruby-on-rails-6, form-with

I have a simple form for creating a new model. The model has an attribute `panel` that is set in the Controller. I think it should not matter, but `panel` is an enum.

```
def new
  @order = Order.new(panel: params[:panel])
end
```

In the view I create the following form (additional attributes omitted because not relevant for the problem)

```
<%= form_with model: @order do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :panel %>
<% end %>
```

#### Problem

The problem is, that tis creates an input field for `panel` with some hashed or encrypted value instead of the correct `panel` value:

```
<input type="hidden" value="TfVtJbT4RBcPdCCqrkap+dA8uhJvotCH02+Isxx9ACmI2a9hcp4dOEszqztFy5A8pfIxqi35SW7BexQfYvq8BQ==" name="order[panel]" id="order_panel">
```

When trying to submit this form, I get an error that makes sense...

> ArgumentError ('TfVtJbT4RBcPdCCqrkap+dA8uhJvotCH02+Isxx9ACmI2a9hcp4dOEszqztFy5A8pfIxqi35SW7BexQfYvq8BQ==' is not a valid panel)

#### Alternatives

I have tried to explicitly specify the value in the form, but this does not change the created HTML and thus still has the same problem.

```
<%= form_with model: @order do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :panel, value: @order.panel %>
<% end %>
```

#### Workaround Solution

The only thing that works so far is to create a `text_field` and set it to hidden

```
<%= form_with model: @order do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :panel, value: @order.panel, hidden: true %>
<% end %>
```

This creates the correct value:

```
<input value="sport" type="text" name="order[panel]" id="order_panel" hidden="hidden">
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Why does `hidden_field` not work as expected? What am I missing?

This is on the newest version of Ruby on Rails (Rails 6.0.2.1).

#### CSP

Upon further investigation, it seems this is somehow related to Content Security Policy and Turbolinks and/or UJS

This is my CSP:

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self, :https
  policy.style_src   :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
  policy.connect_src :self, :https, "http://localhost:3035", "ws://localhost:3035" if Rails.env.development?
end

# If you are using UJS then enable automatic nonce generation
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request { SecureRandom.base64(16) }

# Set the nonce only to specific directives
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w(script-src)
# Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_report_only = true
```

I noticed that sometimes, when navigating around, the browser actually navigates to the link instead of Turbolinks doing their work (even though in these cases, no CSP Violation is logged), where in the same instance with NO CSP, Turbolinks are working as expected.

I have included my Javascript with `nonce: content_security_policy_nonce`

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', nonce: content_security_policy_nonce, 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

If I remove `nonce: content_security_policy_nonce` here, Turbolinks seem to work as expected again...

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on my sandbox rails project `6.0.1`. It works as it supposed

Comment: Thanks, I did not think to test it with a blank project. I've updated that project to Rails 6 just recently. After your comment I looked around and found that the issue seems to come from a CSP configuration: `Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request { SecureRandom.base64(16) }`. Without this, however, UJS is being blocked...

Comment: Anyway, on a clean project it seems to work correctly with my current CSP, even with the nonce enabled as well...

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to open issue on github, if you made update to rails 6 properly. Good luck, though

Comment: @MeXx I am facing this issue now, the only config I have is `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true`. It seems to me that that config is adding a authenticity token via hidden input, but also screwing up the next hidden input. I have added a fake `<%= hidden_field_tag :skip, "bam" %>`, so the action_view doesn't screw the one I want...

Comment: Are you using Firefox for your tests?

Comment: Yes I was using Firefox. Right now, I can not remember anymore if I have tested this in other browsers as well

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified the browser in your question, but there is an issue with [Firefox autocomplete being too aggressive and overriding hidden field values](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520561). The issue is closed but there are people complaining about it using version 75 in may.

Try disabling autocomplete for the given field like so:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :panel, autocomplete: 'off' %>
```

Comment: Its quite some time sine I've hit this issue and i was not able to reproduce the problem quickly anymore, so I can also not verify that this fixes it.

Comment: That is crazy. Thanks. I experienced this with FF 86.0

Comment: Just had the same issue with FF 102.0. Thanks!